# How to update glassfish on 64-bit linux (Fedora 18)

Tags: glassfish, 64-bit, updates, fedora

I am running 64-bit Fedora 18 and trying to update Glassfish 4.  Glassfish's update tool doesn't run 64-bit apparently, and needs 32-bit compatibility libraries.  The glassfish update center release notes don't give any information for what libraries are needed for Fedora.  I've tried installing the libraries for some of the other linux/unix versions listed there, and have tried instructions in many postings I've found on the net, but none of them have worked -- I still get the same error.

Has anyone figured out how to get glassfish's updatetool (or pkg tool) to work on 64-bit Fedora (I suspect this would include a list of additional libs to install for 32-bit compatibility)?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue on FC20 when attempting to update Glassfish using the updatetool.  I decided that the risk from installing 32 bit compatibility on my 64 bit fc20 was greater than the benefit from the glassfish update. I predict the glassfish team will fix this issue in future releases.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem on FC20 by using yum to install these files:
ld-linux.so.2
libstdc++.so.6
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libpangox-1.0.so.0
libSM.so.6
libpng12.so.0
libidn.so.11

Answer (score 0):

I've installed following 32-bit packages in my fedora-25

> dnf -y install glibc.i686 libstdc++.i686 gtk2.i686 pangox-compat.i686
>   libSM.i686 libpng12.i686 libidn.i686

Cheers!